# T-SQL how to get date range for 2 week pay period

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following seed input data:

1. Payperiod start: Dec 3rd
2. Payperiod end: Dec 16

Thats just example how company payroll goes.

Now, I have just 1 date input, for example 12/30 (as today)
I need to output date range for current pay period which will be: Dec 17 to Dec 30

And, same thing if I input Jan 3 - I should get back Dec 31 to Jan 13 2012

Is there any shortcut in T-SQL or I have to do loops?

EDIT: To summarize question. if we know when pay cycle starts (in past) - how do I figure pay period start for given date?

Comment: You need to clarify the question. It's not clear what's it you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: So, we can assume that you do not have a pre-populated table with all payperiods, right?

Comment: @Christoper no, I don't have. I have 1 seed date as in question

Comment: If you created such a table, the question would have a very simple answer. As it stands, the answer would involve some date calculations involving modulus 14 with a base date of Dec 3 2011.

Comment: If I created table I wouldn't ask this question :) But yes, sugestion with modulus 14 is a good one. DATEDIFF for dates and divide. Better then looping going forward..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need some modulo operations and [`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).

```
declare @periodStart datetime
declare @periodEnd datetime

set @periodStart = CAST('2011-12-03' as datetime)
set @periodEnd = CAST('2011-12-16' as datetime)

declare @anyDate datetime
set @anyDate = CAST('2011-12-30' as datetime)

declare @periodLength int
set @periodLength = DATEDIFF(day, @periodStart, @periodEnd) + 1


declare @daysFromFirstPeriod int
set @daysFromFirstPeriod = DATEDIFF(day, @periodStart, @anyDate)
declare @daysIntoPeriod int
set @daysIntoPeriod = @daysFromFirstPeriod % @periodLength

select @periodLength as periodLength, @daysFromFirstPeriod as daysFromFirstPeriod, @daysIntoPeriod as daysIntoPeriod
select DATEADD(day, -@daysIntoPeriod, @anyDate) as currentPeriodStart, DATEADD(day, @periodLength -@daysIntoPeriod, @anyDate) as currentPeriodEnd
```

Gives output

```
periodLength    daysFromFirstPeriod daysIntoPeriod
14              27                  13
```

and

```
currentPeriodStart        currentPeriodEnd
2011-12-17 00:00:00.000   2011-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Please note that the `currentPeriodEnd` is _exclusive_ (as it should be).

Comment: Hmm, that code creates a pay period one day too long. Would changing it to this be correct way to fix it? We use a Sun thru Sat work week BTW. `set @daysIntoPeriod = @daysFromFirstPeriod % @periodLength + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Would the following not work?

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
SELECT @StartDate = '2016-05-01 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SELECT @EndDate = '2017-04-01 00:00:00.000'

DECLARE @Dates TABLE(StartDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME)

WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @Dates (StartDate, EndDate)
SELECT @StartDate - 13, @StartDate WHERE DATEPART(WEEK, @StartDate) % 2 = 1 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @StartDate) = 7

SET @StartDate = @StartDate + 1 
END

-- Check the dates here... should be every 2 weeks
SELECT * FROM @Dates
```