# SQL Server : calculate Bi-Weekly Pay Period Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following to get bi-weekly pay period dates, The week starts on Sat
When I run it assuming today's date is 02/22/2016 I get the following

- Pay Period Start: 02/13/2016
- Pay Period End: 02/23/2016

But it should actually be 02/20/2016 - 3/4/2016 . It seems to be a week off.
If I start the week on Monday, then everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getFirstWeekDayDate (
     @TargetDay DATETIME,
     @strWeekDayName VARCHAR(25) --Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday
)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Return DATE

    --  Set to first of its year
    SET @TargetDay = DATEADD(dd, -DATEPART(dayofyear, @TargetDay) + 1, @TargetDay)

    ;WITH Dates AS
    (
          SELECT @TargetDay AS DateVal
          UNION ALL
          SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, DateVal) AS DateVal
          FROM Dates
          WHERE DATEADD(d, 1, DateVal) < DATEADD(m, 1, @TargetDay)
    )
    SELECT @Return = MIN(DateVal)
    FROM Dates
    WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY,DateVal) = @strWeekDayName

    RETURN @Return
END 
GO

DECLARE
    @periodstart date, @period int, @today date

set @today = '02/22/2016'
set @periodstart = dbo.getFirstWeekDayDate(@today,'Saturday') --get first sat
set @period = datediff(dd,@periodstart,@today)/14

select
    @period AS period,
    dateadd(dd, @period * 14, @periodstart) AS [payPeriodStart],
    dateadd(dd, @period * 14 + 13, @periodstart) AS [payPeriodEnd]
```

Result

```
period      payPeriodStart payPeriodEnd
----------- -------------- ------------
3           2016-02-13     2016-02-26
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL how to get date range for 2 week pay period](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684054/t-sql-how-to-get-date-range-for-2-week-pay-period)

Comment: You are getting the current pay period, just do a dateadd when calling the function to next the next pay period.

Comment: @Ken White - I did use the previous post to determine this - but its a different issue.

Comment: @Chuck - I don't need to get the next pay period - its just the current pay periods are incorrect - it should be 02/20/2016 - 03/04/2016. It seems to be a week off

Comment: The linked question is exactly the same as far as the SQL is concerned. The question is how to return the proper two week pay period based on a given date, which is exactly what you're asking here.

Comment: The function is always going to get you a Saturday, not every other Saturday, If you know your Pay Period (@period) that would be easier to return two week chunks. The way you are doing it now, it will be wrong every other week.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Thank you for all the comments. I decided to let the user specify first pay period end date in the settings and then I used that calculate the rest of the pay periods.