# How to get BiWeekly Dates per month in year with week id, start and end date using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Example: `Jan 2017`

```
Week 1- 01/01/2017 - 01/14/2017

Week 2 - 01/15/2017 - 01/28/2017
```

and so on...

Database : SQL Server

Comment: What's the question? Specify both input table data, and the expected result. Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: See [How to get biweekly dates per month in a year in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058926/how-to-get-biweekly-dates-per-month-in-a-year-in-sql-server) or [T-SQL how to get date range for 2 week pay period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684054/t-sql-how-to-get-date-range-for-2-week-pay-period)

Comment: @jarlh, as an example you can take any month as an input data, I want to divide 52 or 53 weeks in a year into biweekly i.e. 26 or 27 along with start date and end date. Below is example: Input as Jan 2017                                                                                                                        
Output:
 Week_ID Start_Date End_Date
1  1/1/2017                 1/14/2017
2  1/15/2017         1/28/2017

Comment: @Valerica thanks but I do not want to hard code it should be driven based on calendar year and it should take date as an input

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,number,CAST('2017-01-01' AS DATE)) day
    FROM master..spt_values WHERE TYPE = 'p'
    AND number < 366
    )

SELECT 
    DATEPART(WEEK, day) as Week, 
    day as FirstWeekDay,
    dateAdd(day, 6, day) as LastWeekDay
FROM dates
WHERE DATENAME(dw, day) IN ('Monday')
Order by day
```

or regularly 15 days like your example:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,number,CAST('2017-01-01' AS DATE)) day
    FROM master..spt_values WHERE TYPE = 'p'
    AND number < 366
    )

SELECT 
    row_number() over (order by day),
    day as FirstWeekDay,
    dateAdd(day, 13, day) as LastWeekDay
FROM dates
WHERE DATENAME(dw, day) IN ('Sunday')
 and DATEPART(WEEK, day) % 2 = 1
order by day
```

***UPDATE***

You can use this query if your `Calendar` table has all the days:

```
SELECT 
    row_number() over (order by day_date) WeekId,
    day_date as FirstWeekDay,
    dateAdd(day, 6, day_date) as LastWeekDay  --change 6 -> 13 for 2 weeks
FROM Calendar
WHERE DATENAME(dw, day_date) IN ('Monday')    --change day name if you need
-- and DATEPART(WEEK, day_date) % 2 = 1       --remove comment for 2 weeks
order by day_date
```

Comment: thanks a lot and can we modify this query to be a simple select statement using date functions?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Can we write this query as a select statement and modify as I need a select statement with date functions.

Comment: Below query I tried.                                                                                  
SELECT day_date
    ,Cast(Cast(DatePart(yy, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, day_date) / 14 * 14, 0)) AS VARCHAR) + Cast(DatePart(ww, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, day_date) / 14 * 14, 0)) AS VARCHAR) AS INT) AS Week_ID
    ,dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, day_date) / 14 * 14 + 3, 0) AS start_date
    ,dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, day_date) / 14 * 14 + 16, 0) AS End_date
FROM Calendar

Comment: you are welcome, how about Calendar table, what fields are in it? Also you can convert a function this query. For example like a table select * from  dbo.weekOfYear(date_param) or like a column select dbo.getWeekId(date_param),... from...